# Filewatcher returning error. No overload matches delegate

Tags: c#

I've written this method which should check for file changes.

```
public static void watch()    
   {    
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();    
        watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpticusFileLoc"];    
        watcher.Filter = "sigtrades.xml";    
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;    


       // watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    }
```

However, I get this error:
"No overload for 'OnChanged' matches delegate 'System.IO.SystemEventHandler'

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `OnChanged` method needs to have [the following signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventhandler.aspx):

```
void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e);
```

Does it?

Comment: Yup, thats what was missing. Works now. Thanks.